# @user = whatever is selected

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

When a `:user_id` is selected how can we show in `collection_select` that user's challenges? In other words, how can we make `@user` equal to whatever `:user_id` was selected in _dueler_fields?

**duels/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@duel) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :duelers do |dueler| %>
    <%= render 'dueler_fields', :f => dueler %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association f, :duelers do %>
    + Dueler
  <% end %>
  The loser(s) will <%= f.text_field :consequence, placeholder: "Enter Consequence" %>
<% end %>
```

**duels/_dueler_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.select :user_id, User.order(:name).map { |user| [user.full_name, user.id] } %>  will
<%= collection_select(:dueler, :challenge_id, @challenges, :id, :full_challenge) %>
```

**duels_controller**

```
def new
  @duel = Duel.new
  @duel.duelers << Dueler.new(user_id: current_user.id, user_name: current_user.name, user_last_name: current_user.last_name)
  @user = # How can we set this to whatever was selected?
  @challenges = @user.challenges.order(:created_at)
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "duelers", force: true do |t| #belongs_to :user & :challenge & :duel
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "challenge_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
    t.integer  "duel_id",        null: false
    t.boolean  "accept"
    t.string   "user_name"
    t.string   "user_last_name"
    t.string   "challenge_name"
  end

  add_index "duelers", ["duel_id"], name: "index_duelers_on_duel_id", using: :btree

  create_table "duels", force: true do |t| #belongs_to :user & :challenge, has_many :duelers
    t.text     "consequence"
    t.text     "reward"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end
```

### UPDATE

```
<%= f.select :user_id, User.order(:name).map { |user| [user.full_name, user.id] }, include_blank: true, id: "change-challenge-options" %> will
<%= collection_select(:dueler, :challenge_id, @challenges, :id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true) %>

<script> # Doesn't Work
    $( "#change-challenge-options" ).change(function() {
         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '<%= user_challenges_path %>',
            data: {name: $('#change-challenge-options').prop('value')}
         });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You probably will need to solve this with javascript

Comment: I'm open to that @lcguida. I opened a bounty because I can't figure this one out on my own.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/ (Sorry, I don't have the time to really answer your question)

Comment: You can get the `id` of the user with `params[:duel][:user_id]`, no?

Comment: No I'm getting a `nil` value @Ashitaka

Comment: Keep in mind there can be an unlimited amount of `duelers` @Ashitaka for a `duel`. I updated question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

Is not necessary go to controller to get user challenges while refreshing the page, the best form to solve it seems to get a function that returns the challenges to a json petition activated from the "change" action of the users_id select

in users_controller:

```
def challenges
  user = User.find_by_id(user_params)
  @challenges = user.challenges.order(:created_at)
  respond_to |format|
    format.js { render json: @challenges.as_json, status: 200 }
  end
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:user_id)
end
```

in javascript:

```
$("#user_select").on("change", function(){
// make ajax petition with the user: {user_id: $(this).val()}
// and rescue the results to display wher you want
})
```

Comment: Thanks good sir! I think this is on the right track. So I put `def challenges` in users_controller, but then do I change anything in `duels/_dueler_fields.html.erb`? I also played around with your javascript suggestion. Updated question :)